# How does the Outlook.MailItem instance knows what the target Exchanger Server is?

Tags: c#, vsto, sendmail

I try to send an email from a C# app, and I can easily finish this job through the following lines (I am using Outlook 2003, and have my outlook account):

```
Outlook.ApplicationClass oapp = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
omessage = oapp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
omessage.To = "abc@cba.com";
omessage.Subject = "Send From WinForm";
omessage.Body = "Hi, This message is send from a winform project.";
omessage.Send();
```

Based on the above code, the email can be sent successfully (although there a warning box will be shown before sending the email).

My question is: how does this `omessage` item knows where my Exchange server is, while I never configured my Exchange Server in this app?

Does there exist any way to get the Exchange Server Name from the code side? Because I really need this server address.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your using a C# outlook dll\add-in, your application uses outlook to send this mailitem. All properties including the exchange server address, are configured in outlook. Here's a method which exposes the exchange server address in code:

```
Outlook.ApplicationClass oapp = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
Outlook.NameSpace ns = oapp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
ns.Logon();

string ExchangeServer = ns.ExchangeMailboxServerName;
```

Note that you must define a Outlook.namespace property in order to get the address via MAPI